# How do I change a HTML ID with Javascript on page load after getting window size?

Tags: javascript, html, navigation

I am wondering how I can use Javascript to get a windows size and then set (really clear) an HTML ID with it.

I am currently working on a site that has a "default" navigation ID of "access" which I want to blank out if the windows size is less than 800 px wide.

This is the page I am working on and if the ID is cleared I can then setup the mobile navigation to work with bootstrap.

`window.onload = function() {

```
var w = window.innerWidth;

if(w < 800) {
    document.getElementById('access').removeAttribute('id');
}
```

}

window.onload = function() {

```
var w = window.innerWidth;

if(w < 800) {
    document.getElementById('access').removeAttribute('id');
}
```

}

window.onresize = function() {

```
var w = window.innerWidth;

if(w < 800) {
    document.getElementById('access').removeAttribute('id');
}
```

}

Comment: Your code has to go in the question. You can't link to live sites for us to debug.

Comment: why not use CSS media queries ?

Comment: Not really recommended to set and unset IDs, use some other way to keep track of things.

Comment: I'm going to use a media query too, but this id is being used with other Javascript functions to display the menu on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
```

to get the width of the page.

and then,

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(w < 800) {
        document.getElementById('access').removeAttribute('id');
    }
}
```

You probably want to add this functionality in resize too.

EDIT: put the code in `window.onload`

Based on the comment,

```
window.onload = function() {
    var accessElem = document.getElementById('access');
    var updateAccess = function() { 
        var w = window.innerWidth;
        if(w < 800) {
            accessElem.removeAttribute('id');
        }
        else {
            accessElem.setAttribute('id', 'access');
        }
    };
    window.onresize = updateAccess;    // call updateAccess on resize
    updateAccess();                    // call once on load to set it.
};
```

Also, in my opinion, adding/removing `id` is not a great idea.

Comment: Hi Pratyush,

Thank you for your response that defiantly worked. I am realizing I need to also clear his on window resize so that if it falls below 800 that get cleared. Is there a way to set the blank id if the user then resizes the window again greater than 800?

`window.onload = function() {
    
    var w = window.innerWidth;

    if(w < 800) {
        document.getElementById('access').removeAttribute('id');
    }
}

window.onresize = function() {
    
    var w = window.innerWidth;

    if(w < 800) {
        document.getElementById('access').removeAttribute('id');
    }
}`